# Vue single file components: Printing component element from child component

Tags: vue.js

I'm using @vue/vli 4.1.1 with single file components.  A simplified structure of my application looks like this:

```
src
├── App.vue
├── assets
├── components
│   ├── PrintRecipe.vue
│   └── Recipe.vue
└── main.js
```

Inside the Recipe component, I would like to include a print button and its functionality, as implemented in the PrintRecipe component. When the button is pressed, the `#recipe` element from the Recipe component should be printed.

Here is a dummy version of Recipe.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="other-content">
            ...
        </div> 
        <div id="recipe">
            ...
        </div> 
        <PrintRecipe/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import PrintRecipe from './PrintRecipe.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    PrintRecipe
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

and this is a dummy version of PrintRecipe.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="printRecipe">Print recipe</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Printd } from 'printd';

export default {
  mounted() {      
    this.d = new Printd()
  },
  methods: {
    printRecipe () {
      this.d.print( this.$el, [this.cssText])
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Currently this opens a print view, where the document to be printed only contains "Print recipe".

Is there a way that I can access the elements from the template of Recipe.vue in order to be able to print them?

I have done some research and so far I only see information on how to access data from the parent component, not elements.

Comment: Do you have the `data` you want to be printed in `PrintRecipe`?

Comment: Not in the current implementation, no.  I was hoping to be able to use the PrintRecipe component on multiple recipe components in the future.  The element I want to print from  the recipe components contains a combination of text and data.

Comment: Well assuming the combination of text and data can be converted to an `Object`.
Why not pass that `Object` as a `prop` to `PrintRecipe`?

Comment: Thats a good suggestion!  I am new to Vue so I hadn't thought of that.  I Will try it out.

Comment: You can start here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: Thank you, this led me on to discover slots, which is perfect for this purpose.  See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, [Vue slots](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-pass-html-content-through-components-with-vue-slots/) was what I needed.

The PrintRecipe component should have a slot, to where the element that should be printed is inserted.

PrintRecipe.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot/>
        <button @click="printRecipe">Print recipe</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Printd } from 'printd';

export default {
  mounted() {      
    this.d = new Printd()
  },
  methods: {
    printRecipe () {
      this.d.print( this.$el, [this.cssText])
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The insertion is done inside Recipe.vue by expanding the `PrintRecipe` element in the following way:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="other-content">
            ...
        </div> 
        <PrintRecipe>
            <div id="recipe">
                ...
            </div> 
        </PrintRecipe>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import PrintRecipe from './PrintRecipe.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    PrintRecipe
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not the only way how it can be done but a good use case for slot in case you need a reusable component.

Answer (score 2):

Either `Recipe` parent component can handle the interaction, `PrintRecipe` becomes presentation component:

*Recipe.vue*

```
...
<div ref="recipe">...</div> 
<PrintRecipe v-on:print="printRecipe" ref="printRecipe" />
...

...
methods: {
    printRecipe() {
      this.d.print( this.$refs.recipe.$el, [this.cssText])
    }
}
...
```

*PrintRecipe.vue*

```
...
methods: {
    printRecipe() {
      this.$emit('print');
    }
}
...
```

Or `PrintRecipe` child get receive necessary data from `Recipe` parent to handle the interaction, such as a reference to DOM element:

```
...
<div ref="recipe">...</div> 
<PrintRecipe />
...
```

*PrintRecipe.vue*

```
...
methods: {
    printRecipe() {
      this.d.print(this.$parent.$refs.recipe.$el, [this.cssText])
    }
}
...
```

Whether components have to communicate through `$parent`, props or event bus depends on the case.

Comment: It is interesting to see the relations between elements being used, like in `this.$parent.$refs.recipe.$el`.  I hadn't thought of this method.  I my use case it is not ideal however, since I intend to reuse the PrintRecipe component.

Comment: It's acceptable only if the relationship between PrintRecipe and printable component is direct parent-child (could be not Recipe but something else). In any other case assumptions on the hierarchy ($parent.$parent, etc) are considered bad practice. $parent was borrowed from AngularJS and its flaws are already well-known.

Answer (score 1):

Send a custom Vue event on clicking the button back to the `Recipe.vue` component

```
export default {
  mounted() {      
    this.d = new Printd()
  },
  methods: {
    printRecipe () {
      this.$emit('recipeClicked'); // custom event
    }
  }
}
```

From the `Recipe.vue` you can receive the event and write your logic to show the content. Here is my logic;

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="other-content">
            ...
        </div> 
        <div id="recipe" v-show="showContent">
            ...
        </div> 
        <PrintRecipe @recipeClicked="showContent=true"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import PrintRecipe from './PrintRecipe.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    PrintRecipe
  },
  data:()=>{
    return {
      showContent:false
    }
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: I like the idea of sending a custom event.  But isn't this missing the `d.print(...)` command?  If that would have to be placed inside Recipe.vue to be triggered there after the event is caught, that would make re-using the PrintRecipe a bit more of a hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm not familiar with that library. Thought you can use the logic.

Comment: Yes, it will for sure be useful in my future developments, thanks!